# Assiging elements into the lower triangular part of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, assign, diagonal

I'm creating a diagonal matrix in MATLAB using `eye(3)`. How can I assign the number "2" only to the  elements under the main diagonal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `tril` has an extra argument that controls which lower triangular exactly to use.

```
A = eye(3) + 2*tril(ones(3), -1);
```

Comment: I removed it because it completely falls short when compared to yours.

Comment: @EitanT "completely" is a very strong word. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Hmm... okay then. I've posted a different approach, depending on the OP's desire.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in *assigning* elements into an already existent matrix, you can use [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) in similar fashion to Shai's answer and combine it with logical indexing. For example:

```
A = eye(3);
idx = tril(true(size(A)), -1); % # Lower triangular half
A(idx) = 2
```

Which should yield the desired result:

```
A =

     1     0     0
     2     1     0
     2     2     1
```

If you're at the stage of creating such a matrix, then you should generate it like Shai suggests.

Comment: I copied and paste your code:

A = eye(3);
idx = tril(true(size(A), -1)); 
A(idx) = 2

But I still get the identity matrix. What do i do wrong?

Comment: @user1928113 sorry, I forgot to close the parentheses after `size(A)`, and you misplaced them. Please try the fixed answer.